# Screen repeatedly goes blank, flickering off and on. Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, screen, flicker

My screen keeps switching off for about a second, then switching back on. This is getting increasingly annoying. It can happen several times a minute, or not happen at all for an hour or so. It always happens when I'm doing something, but I can't say specifically what.

My computer is a desktop Lenovo with graphics card built-in to the motherboard. The OS is Lubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. The monitor is an HP, quite old but no problems before. It seems to be using the driver i915.

I see many similar problems mentioned on the internet, but I can't follow any solutions for older systems from a long time ago. Could this be a kernel thing? I driver thing? Can anyone help please?

Comment: Good question. All cables and sockets have been unplugged, cleaned and plugged back in again.

Comment: Depending on how often it occurs; if it's occurring quickly after machine is turned on etc, I'd likely boot a *live* system and see if it occurs there. I'd firstly try it on the like kernel/stack you're using now (*I assume you're using the HWE kernel but you don't specify, ie. 5.11 for 20.04.3*) then the other stack (eg. GA or 5.4 for 20.04). The stack is chosen by ISO used to install with Lubuntu. Does it still occur when doing same things (ie. here I'm trying to see if it occurs on the *live* media & ~unaltered stack).  Then I'd repeat test with a somewhat different stack (occur here? etc.)

Comment: uname -r says:
5.11.0-44-generic
I've used Ubuntu for over a decade now, but some of its inner workings are still a mystery to me. This is one of them. I could try running a live CD, but it would have to be the one I installed from or a newer release of Lubuntu, unless any other flavours fit on a CD anymore.